Windows Executable on Linux Samba Server
this is my first help request but i follow the site since a lot...I wrote an application in c# to interact with MariaDB, i set up a slackware SQL server and because the server joined an Active Directory domain i've installed also samba. Everything works, i can access sql tables throught my application and copy files with samba shares. Now the problem, i want to install the application exe on this linux server and execute it from windows machines, so i can keep it up to date from just one place. This  works, but because the application must access to a network samba share and load some pdf files from it, this doesn't work! I mean if i execute the application from the linux server, (that has in the same directory the shared pdf dir), the program doesn't "see" the shared pdf directory.
I tried to change the path with IP address, mounting to a local drive letter, etc but it doesn't work. The application "see" the samba share only if i have the exe on the local computer, i could use it this way but i will have to distribute it on many pcs, Does anyone know if it's possible to fix this? Thanks for you patience and support!
Bye!
PS.: I noticed that if i copy the path to a windows explorer window it asks me for username and password, could be this the problem, authentication?

To be more specific the FileInfo class returns me that the file not exists!

Well, thanks, but it works, i mean i copied the exe on my linux server and i created a link in my windows laptop, if i execute the program it works, and i already has mapped the drive in window, the problem is something like the application desn't recognize the right paths...

Yes, maybe i missed it...I know that everything works locally, but if so, why the path for pdf files (E.g. F:\pdf) is not recognized by the app? I tried to open the link, the app should open, inside windows explorer and it works, but when i try through my application the FileInfo class says "file not found"...

Thank you very much for your help, i don't know how to find out the way to understand my app recognize the paths, so i decided to install copies of the application on each computer i'll need it and share the pdfs on the server, i will map the shares with the same letter on each computer so it will work...Thanks again
